# Highlighting Todays Work Day of the Week in an HTML Table using only CSS/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html-table, calendar, highlight, dayofweek

I would like my computer to automatically highlight todays day of the week in a table row.

The table has all the weekdays in a separate row, and has a fixed number of seven rows, starting with the least pleasant day of all days, Monday or *Maandag* in Dutch.

Lets say its Tuesday today or *Dinsdag* in Dutch, then the second row should be highlighted like so:

[image]

However, the problem is that instead of todays day, the next day is highlighted.
Probably I've overlooked something small.
The solution can be onlly in HTML/CSS/JS/JQuery and not in PHP.
I have made a demo of my half-working half-defective exemaple:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0bvtzd1/4/

```js
workday();

function workday() {
  var d = new Date().getDay();
  document.getElementById("day-"+d).classList.add('today');    
}
```

```css
.today { 
  background-color: #FFD700 !important; 
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: .5em 0;
}

th, td {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #EEE}
```

```html
<table id="weekdagtabel">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="day-1">
            <td>Maandag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-2">
            <td>Dinsdag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-3">
            <td>Woensdag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-4">
            <td>Donderdag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-5">
            <td>Vrijdag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-6">
            <td>Zaterdag</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-7">
            <td>Zondag</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Comment: You simply need to decrement the day by 1 `var d = new Date().getDay() - 1;`, because `getDay()` method returns the rank of the day starting with 1 not 0

Answer (score 1):

Happens because Monday is the first day of the week not 0th.

Start numbering ids from 1 not 0

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense! I think I overcompensated by starting counting from zero, thinking that computers count from Sunday, which even then does not make any sense. Your code fixed my thought confusion.

Comment: They actually do, you thought right. How you need to number ids is 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
or you can just swap Zondag with Maandag and don't even change the code. They do start from 0-6 but the 0th day is considered Sunday, so Monday becomes 1

Comment: Suddently today Sunday on the holiest of days, the code shows the following error: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')_ ?!

Comment: [Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/sanodzegg/rdyes760/). Also you can try something like this to check if it works on Sundays `var d = new Date("May 22, 2022 14:15:00").getDay();`

Answer (score 1):

The getDay() function returns a number from 0 to 6, indicating Sunday to Saturday. Since, the id values are from Monday to Sunday, shift the numbers cyclically backwards by 1 using modulo operator. By performing the shift, Sunday(0) from the getDay() becomes Sunday(6) in the HTML.

```js
workday();

function workday() {
  var d = new Date().getDay();
  d = (d + 6)%7
  document.getElementById("day-"+d).classList.add('today');    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The code works indeed and I understand now the variable count extension where 6 can be 7 depending if the id's start with 0 or 1.

Comment: Suddently today Sunday on the holiest of days, both your code and my original code show the following error: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')_ ?!

Comment: Since the id starts from 1 in the updated code, you can add 1 to the line with the modulo operator, d = (d + 6) % 7 + 1. This should resolve the error.